# Cancel click after dragging

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have drag event like this

```js
$('.dragDiv').draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {},
  stop: function(event, ui) {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;" class='dragDiv'>
  <a onclick='console.log("clicked");'>test</a>
</div>
```

In this case, `dragDiv` has the link **test** inside.

If you drag the div by grabbing `test link`.

the link fires after dragging.

I want to cancel the firing the link after dragging.

How can I make it??

Answer (score 1):

You can add `pointer-events: none` to `a` tag to prevent click event

```js
$('.dragDiv').draggable({
    start:function(event,ui){
    },
    stop:function(event,ui){
        
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;" class='dragDiv'>
<a style="pointer-events: none;" onclick='console.log("clicked");'>test</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the dragged element and then inside the `click` event handler you check if the element have that class, but as you see I had to add timeout function since the click will be queued and executed after drag is finished, not sure if there is a better way:

**onclick event**

```js
$('.dragDiv').draggable({
    start:function(event,ui){
      $('.dragDiv').addClass('disable-click')
    },
    stop:function(event,ui){
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('.dragDiv').removeClass('disable-click')  
      }, 100);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;" class='dragDiv'>
<a onclick='if(!this.parentElement.classList.contains("disable-click")) {console.log("clicked");}'>test</a>
</div>
```

another option is to handle mouse event `onmouseup` that would be a cleaner way without settimeout function:

**onmouseup event**

```js
$('.dragDiv').draggable({
    start:function(event,ui){
      $('.dragDiv').addClass('disable-click')
    },
    stop:function(event,ui){
      $('.dragDiv').removeClass('disable-click');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;" class='dragDiv'>
<a onmouseup='if(!this.parentElement.classList.contains("disable-click")) {console.log("clicked");}'>test</a>
</div>
```